# Error No rule to make target PIC24 assembler

Tags: assembly, makefile, pic, mplab, pic24

I'm trying to make a simple program to turn on a LED using a pic24fv32ka301 in assembler but I can't get it work, when trying to compile in MPLAB using de ASM30 compiler it throws the following error:

```
 nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:84: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
 make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jafet/MPLABXProjects/prueba1.X'
 nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
 make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'build/default/production/main.o', 
 needed by 'dist/default/production/prueba1.X.production.hex'.  Stop.
 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

the code is the following

```
    .equ __24FV32KA301
.include "p24FV32KA301.inc"

 ; config __FBS 0xF ; 
 config __FBS, OFF & OFF
 ; config __FGS 0x3 ; 
 config __FGS, OFF & OFF
 ; config __FOSCSEL 0xE7 ; 
 config __FOSCSEL, FRCDIV & ANA & HP & ON
 ; config __FOSC 0xFF ; 
 config __FOSC, NONE & ON & HS & SOSCHP & CSDCMD
 ; config __FWDT 0xFF ; 
 config __FWDT, PS32768 & PR128 & ON & OFF
 ; config __FPOR 0xFF ; 
 config __FPOR, BOR3 & OFF & ON & PRI & V20 & ON
 ; config __FICD 0x83 ; 
 config __FICD, PGx1
 ; config __FDS 0xDF ; 
 config __FDS, DSWDTPSF & LPRC & ON & ON

.text 
__reset:

MOV #__SP_init, WREG15
MOV #__SPLIM_init, WREG0    
MOV WREG0,SPLIM 
NOP

MOV 0X70,OSCCON 
MOV 0x00,WREG0
MOV WREG0, TRISA
MOV 0xFF,WREG0
MOV WREG0,TRISB

LOOP:
MOV PORTB,WREG0
MOV WREG0,PORTA
GOTO LOOP

DONE: 
.END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have there has nothing to do with your code. Its an error with your Makefile.

Comment: mmmm but I didn't modify the MakeFile do I need to add something?

Comment: Your only showing errors generated by the `make` command itself, you haven't shown any errors generated by the actual assembler you're using.  If only make is printing errors and ASM30 isn't printing errors then the assumption is that there's something wrong with your Makefile.

Comment: YES, and thanks, there was the problem, I had to updrage de assembler and the problem was gone, then change structure of the file because it has erros too